# A sum involving binomial coefficients and its evaluation using the Gamma function

Tags: binomial-coefficients, gamma-function

Does anyone know how to prove (or a reference for) the following identity for positive integers $r$:
$$\sum_{i=0}^r (-1)^i{r\choose i}\frac{1}{ir+1}=
\frac{\Gamma(1+1/r)\Gamma(r+1)}{\Gamma(r+1+1/r)}$$

Comment: Hints: $\frac{1}{ir+1} = \int_0^1 x^{ir}\,dx$ ... binomial theorem ... Beta function

Answer (score 1):

Maple?

Input: $$f:=(-1)^i*r!/i!/(r-i)!/(r*i+1)$$
$$\text{SumTools}[\text{DefiniteSummation}](f,i=0..r)$$
Output:$${\Gamma \left( r+1 \right) \Gamma \left( {\frac {r+1}{r}} \right) 
 \left( \Gamma \left( {\frac {{r}^{2}+r+1}{r}} \right)  \right) ^{-1}}
$$
Maple uses the algorithms of Gosper, Wilf, Zeilberger and others using telescoping sums. It should be able to convert the computation into a human readable proof, a so-called certificate.

Comment: Maybe, but there is already a one-line proof in the comments by Gerald Edgar...

Comment: First, both solutions were posted nearly simultaneously. Secondly, the maple solution is valuable since it is short, elementary, and, most importantly, the method is much more general.

Comment: this is also true